# Error: Image is not display in CactusList Page

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs, postman

I am currently developing a ecommerce project using Laravel and react.js. I want to show the available cactus list in my admin panel. So, I created the table and add data to the table using laravel and react.js. The image is automatically saved to "cactus_Type" folder in the project folder. I want to show all the available cactus types that I have added to Database. So, I have created a table to show the available cactus. Only ID, Name is display on the table, the image is not display.

CactusController I use:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Cactus;
    class CactusController extends Controller
    {
     //
     function addCactus(Request $req)
     {
       $cactus=new Cactus;
       $cactus->name=$req->input('name');
       $cactus->file_path=$req->file('file')->store('cactus_Type');
       $cactus->save();
       return $cactus;
     }

     function Cactuslist()
     {
        return Cactus :: all();
     }

     function Cactusdelete($id)
     {
      $result= Cactus ::where('id',$id)->delete(); 
      if($result)
     {
        return["result"=>"Cactus has been deleted"];
     }
     else
     {
        return["result"=>"Operation Failed"];
     }
     return $result;
    }

    }
```

Migration Cacti Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cacti', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('file_path');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

CactusList.js in react.js

```
import Cactus from './Cactus';
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
function CactusList()
{
   //Define state
   const [data,setData]=useState([]);
   useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
   },[])
  async function deleteOperation(id)
 {
    let result= await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/Cactusdelete/"+id, {
        method:'DELETE'
    });
    result=await result.json();
    console.warn(result)
    getData();
 }
async function getData()
{
    let result= await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/Cactuslist");
    result= await result.json();
    setData(result)
}

return(
    <div>
        <Cactus/>
        <div className="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h1>Available Cactus List</h1>
        <Table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Image</td>
                <td>Operations</td>
            </tr>
            {
                data.map((item)=>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{item.id}</td>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td><img style={{width:100}} src ={"http://localhost:8000/"+item.file_path}/></td>
                        <td><span onClick={()=>deleteOperation(item.id)} className="delete">Delete</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <Link to={"updateCactus/"+item.id}>
                            <span className="update">Update</span>
                            </Link>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }
        </Table>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
export default CactusList
```

I am getting this error in console

```
 GET http://localhost:8000/cactus_Type/BEOPiwLF3EU9k2ggn8abKxAXgDVDpS38Up7UZ2OZ.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

This is how the outcome show,
[Available Cactus List Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKzDe.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Where are you hosting your images? In your backend or the frontend? The url that you are passing as `src` for `img` should have the image hosted.

Comment: Since I am doing my project from my own pc. I will upload picture from the folder of the pc and save it in my project Database. In Database, the file path will be saved and picture will be saved inside the project folder .

Comment: You need to host the picture at a URL which is accessible, unless you have that the image won't load. It can be a localhost path if you want to serve it only for your local, but a server has to serve it nonetheless. It can be a static server as well if you want.

Comment: so, can you please tell me what exactly need to be change in above coding in order to get a outcome?